# Hat is your way to organize and archive works

Tags: file-management

what is the best way or your way to organize file on windows to save your old design works.
do you use a particoular software like adobebridge or as i do by orgnizing files in folders? I'm always in doubt if is better by writing a date like 20180211 or by committant.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Best File Management Practices when you have thousands of Files](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/92246/best-file-management-practices-when-you-have-thousands-of-files) and https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/16173/easy-archiving-organising-your-graphic-elements-for-later-use and https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/4849/how-can-i-effectively-manage-all-my-design-assets and https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/21766/how-do-you-manage-samples-of-physical-design-projects

Answer (score 0):

There are plenty of archiving (more specificly: asset management) tools available - free and paid.

Here's a link to an introductory guide to the subject: https://photography.tutsplus.com/tutorials/how-to-choose-asset-management-software-for-your-digital-picture-archive--cms-24356

Archiving software have one problem: Once you start to use one, it's difficult to be without it and there's no practical (=easy also for non-programmers) way to change the system. This is a perfect opportunity to business productivity optimization. Imagine this:

- you have purchased a good asset management system or took a free one
- the software is good => its price starts to rise. It was initially free or paid once say $100,- but one year later updates (necessary, beacause Windows evolve) are available only for the rented version which costs say $30,-/month/user

**One possiblity without archiving software:** Save every file to a project folder which determines the original reason of the existence of that file. In different disk drive keep other folders for different classifications. For example folders for different customers, content types and formats.

In those folders do not save the files nor folders, but shortcuts. You can drag a created shortcut into as many folders as you want without losing it, if the disk drive is different.

It really pays off to carefully decide what classifications you need and do the archiving job as soon as possible.

Windows shortcuts are much more useful if they have preview stamps of the images. Windows has got several extensions which make previews for different image formats. There are also third party file browsers which show much more previews than non-extended windows.